# How to exclude gaps in date ranges made with mysql window functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got sales per working day (the fourth and fifth were a weekend):

```
date        sales
2019-05-02  5
2019-05-03  5
2019-05-06  5
2019-05-07  10
2019-05-08  10
```

I'd like to create date ranges with the same sales. But the ranges should not include gaps. So what I need is this:

```
from_date   to_date     sales
2019-05-02  2019-05-03  5
2019-05-06  2019-05-06  5
2019-05-07  2019-05-08  10
```

That's my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
       MIN(date) OVER(my_window) AS from_date,
       MAX(date) OVER(my_window) AS to_date,
       sales
    FROM sales_table
    WINDOW my_window AS (
        PARTITION BY sales
    )
) AS window_query
GROUP BY from_date, to_date, sales
```

Delivers that:

```
from_date   to_date     sales
2019-05-02  2019-05-06  5
2019-05-07  2019-05-08  10
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: The ___What I want___ Does not seem to be consistent. Maybe you should have another look at that

Comment: I don't want to sum up the sales. I want to say: From the second to the third, the sales were each 5. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can solve it by subtracting a sequence of numbers from the dates.  Consecutive dates will have the same date:

```
SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date), sales
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sales ORDER BY date) as seqnum
       FROM sales_table s
      ) s
GROUP BY sales, date - interval seqnum day;
```

Comment: Wow, that's clever! Thank you very much!